# Meteor.js - automatically updating one Mongo collection when another mongo collection changes?

Tags: meteor

So I have an external process that periodically updates a collection in the Mongo database backing my Meteor app.  I would like my Meteor app to take a particular action and update a different collection every time this first collection is updated.  Is there a way I can listen to a collection in Meteor?  Note, that I'm only concerned about the server side here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an observer:

```
CollectionOne.find({createdAt: {$gte: new Date()}}).observe({
    added: function (document) {
        // Do something to collection 2
    },
    changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
        // ...
    },
    removed: function (oldDocument) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

So `added`, `changed` and `removed` are fired when the documents from `CollectionOne` are added, changed or removed respectively.

You can use the callbacks of these to do something to a second Collection, or do other logic.

Also, note you can change the query. I've used `createdAt` to ensure that the observer only fires for new documents. (If they have a createdAt field with the date they were inserted).

The reason for this is the `observe` fires once initially for every document that matches the query.